# Issues on Chrome with sticky menu

Tags: jquery, menu, sticky

I am using jQuery Waypoint for my sticky menu. It works perfect on Firefox, but not on Chrome. Any ideas?

Here is the website:
[website](http://alexandrugorgos.com/niculaegiani.ro)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this in the newest version of Chrome and it works just fine. Try pressing CTRL + F5. This forces a refresh which means the browser is forced to reload all content including CSS files and JS files.